# default initialization value for jaxb generated class

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf, wsdl2java

I have a simple class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class foo {
    boolean bar = true;

    boolean getBar () {
        return this.bar;
    }

    void setBar (boolean bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Note, that bar is initialized to true when the class is created.

When this class is generated from the generated jaxb schema it loses the default initialization. Is there any jaxb annotation that can set the default initialization values? Or any other way to do this?

UPDATE:
Adding @XmlElement (defaultvalue="true"), as follows:

```
@XmlElement (defaultvalue="true")
boolean getBar () {
    return this.bar;
}
```

generates the following schema:

```
<xs:element default="true" name="bar" type="xs:boolean"/>
```

However, Java's implementation of JAXB does not honor this when reconstructing the class. The generated class looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class foo {
    @XmlElement(defaultValue = "true")
    protected boolean bar;

    boolean getBar () {
        return this.bar;
    }

    void setBar (boolean bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Notice that we have lost the default initialization value of true for bar.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB annotation `@XmlElement(defaultValue = "defValue")` is what you need. ([javadoc](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.1/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html))

Comment: I believe that specifies the default value during unmarshalling, if the field is null - not the default value of in the schema

Comment: Look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423414/does-jaxb-support-default-schema-values?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I added, @XmlElement(defaultValue = "defValue"), but as you can see that is not honored by java's jaxb implementation when generating the class - are you suggesting that this is limitation in java's implementation of jaxb?

Comment: As I remember when you create java stubs from *.xsd files this annotations will be created by default. Did you use xjc (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/jaxb/xjc.html)?

Comment: I used cxf's wsdl2java. I am not sure what that uses internally. I will investigate.

Comment: @prmatta: Internally, I think it uses the schema generator that's part of the JAXB core for the parts you're talking about. (For the WSDL parts it does something different, of course.)